# SQL query that will retrieve set containing all entries from another set

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following relations in my db:

**Organization:** information about political and economical organizations.
name: the full name of the organization
abbreviation: its abbreviation

**isMember:** memberships in political and economical organizations.
organization: the abbreviation of the organization
country: the code of the member country

**geo_desert:** geographical information about deserts
desert: the name of the desert
country: the country code where it is located
province: the province of this country

My task is to retrieve organizations which have within their members full set of countries with deserts. This organization can have also countries without deserts. So I have a set of countries with deserts and every organization in result should have all of them as members and arbitrary amount of other (no desert) countries.

I tried so far to write following code, but it doesn't work.

```
WITH CountriesWithDeserts AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT country
    FROM dbmaster.geo_desert        
), OrganizationsWithAllDesertMembers AS (
    SELECT organization 
    FROM dbmaster.isMember AS ism 
    WHERE (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM  CountriesWithDeserts          
            EXCEPT
            SELECT country
            FROM dbmaster.isMember
            WHERE organization = ism.organization
        )
    ) IS NULL
), OrganizationCode AS (
    SELECT name, abbreviation
    FROM dbmaster.Organization  
)
SELECT oc.name AS Organization
FROM OrganizationCode AS oc, OrganizationsWithAllDesertMembers AS owadm
WHERE oc.abbreviation=owadm.organization;
```

**UPD:** DBMS says: "ism.organization is not defined"
I'm using DB2/LINUXX8664 9.7.0

Output should look like this:

NAME
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    African, Caribbean, and Pacific Countries
    African Development Bank
    Agency for Cultural and Technical Cooperation
    Andean Group

Comment: What is your expected output from this query? post your input as well

Comment: what doesn't work about your query? is there an error or is it just not returning what you are expecting?

Comment: Wrote in UPD the error from DBMS

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is you're not sending `ism`aslias into the sub select to your sub select, but only the "first" sub-select. It's not known in that context.  (You have yoo many sub-selects and CTEs IMO, I think you should simplify it using joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest way to handle this is by using `group by` and `having`.  You just want to focus on the deserts, so the rest of the countries don't matter.

```
select m.organization
from isMember m join
     geo_desert d
     on m.country = d.country
group by m.organization
having count(distinct m.country) = (select count(distinct d.country) from geo_desert);
```

The `having` clause simply counts the number of matching (i.e. desert) countries and checks that all are included.

Comment: You are missing `count` in your subquery.

Comment: Thank you! I used your idea of JOIN, GROUP BY and HAVING  in my code and it worked. Got 10 organizations as a result from total 153.

Answer (score 1):

Word it like this: You are looking for organizations for which not exists a desert country they don't include.

```
select *
from organization o
where not exists
(
  select country from geo_desert
  except
  select country from ismember
  where organization = o.abbreviation
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it also as an optional solution.

Comment: It works and gives the same result as with previous method.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two equivalent solutions:

First:

```
WITH CountriesWithDeserts AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT country
    FROM dbmaster.geo_desert        
), OrganizationsWithAllDesertMembers AS (
    SELECT ism.organization 
    FROM dbmaster.isMember AS ism
    JOIN CountriesWithDeserts AS cwd
    ON ism.country = cwd.country
    GROUP BY ism.organization
    HAVING count(ism.country) = (SELECT count(*) FROM CountriesWithDeserts)
), OrganizationCode AS (
    SELECT name, abbreviation
    FROM dbmaster.Organization  
)
SELECT oc.name AS Organization
FROM OrganizationCode AS oc, OrganizationsWithAllDesertMembers AS owadm
WHERE oc.abbreviation=owadm.organization;
```

Second:

```
WITH CountriesWithDeserts AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT country
    FROM dbmaster.geo_desert        
)
SELECT org.name AS Organization
FROM dbmaster.Organization AS org
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM  CountriesWithDeserts          
    EXCEPT
    SELECT country
    FROM dbmaster.isMember
    WHERE organization = org.abbreviation
);
```